# How to use Firebase in swift? Can't write date to Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in Firebase and be going to use Firebase.

Install pod 'Firebase/Core' pod 'Firebase/Database' coacopods and create Firebase database. And configure ApDelegate.swift file, connect GoogleService-info.plist file to my project and so on. Anyway in creating App, Firebase says my app connect to Firebase(the last step of ios app creating in Firebase).

And I use follow command:

```
import UIKit 
import Firebase 
import FirebaseDatabase

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("someid/name").setValue("mike")
}
```

But there is no error message and firebase. 
I am using xcode 10.1 and tested on emulator.
How to solve this issue. Please advance me if anyone can solve this issue. Thanks.

EDIT: Suggested code to try. See comments

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("someid/name").setValue("mike", withCompletionBlock: { err, ref in
        if let err = err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("data succesfully saved")
        }
    })
}
```

[image: screenshot after run code]

Showed item is created manually

[image: screenshot for permission]

[image: log screenshot]

Comment: How do you know nothing was written? What did you check? Can you show a screenshot of the database after the code has run?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Add screenshot. pls check it. As u can see nothing is saved.

Comment: Thanks for those screenshots. I don't immediately see what could be causing the problem. Can you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/Database#setloggingenabled_:) and check your logging output for anything that seems relevant?

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. I added my code and log screenshot. Sorry but I am new. so I don't understand well. Could you provide more detail?

Comment: The code in your question is correct and will store that data in a node /fb_root/someid/name: "mike". However, there are a number of things that will prevent it from working. Fortunately, the .setValue function can be followed by a [closure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)setValue:withCompletionBlock:) that will handle errors. I added an EDIT to your question with some code to try. Let us know what the result is; either an error will be printed or it will say it was succesful

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of textual content. Instead include the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0):

You could be encountering multiple problems.

1. Didn't add the GoogleService-info.plist then close the project before 'pod init' and 'pod install'
2. You didn't open the .xcworkspace file (This is where all the coding is done after installing Firebase)
3. When adding to the database it is best to use .updateChildValues(["Username": "RandomUser"])

   ref.child("Users").child("random-id").updateChildValues(["Username": "RandomUser"])
4. If you did all of that then try grabbing your database URL from firebase and do:

   let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "your-database-url")